# Updating to ASDF 3.x in CLISP

Tags: macos, common-lisp, clisp, asdf

I am trying to update ASDF in CLISP 2.49 (on Mac OS Sierra) to version 3.x.
I have now version 2.26 of ASDF.
I have tried everything I found online: I downloaded the latest version of ASDF as indicated in https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/ but then when I eval `(require "asdf")`, as indicated in the manual (https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Upgrading-ASDF) nothing happens, I still have version 2.26.
The manual also tells to load the file `asdf.lisp`, but the file is missing from the new version folder.
I discovered that quicklisp had its own version of `asdf.lisp` and `asdf.fas`, which seem to be the ones being loaded, but I don't see how to replace them with any new version.
I have tried so many things now that I'm afraid I'm screwing the system up.

Does anyone know how to upgrade ASDF to a version >= 3.0 reliably and step by step?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you install CLISP?

Comment: I used home-brew: brew install clisp

Comment: I think homebrew does not distribute asdf with clisp.

Comment: It could be. I don't remember if it came with it or whether I installed it apart. The fact is that I have version 2.26 and I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 8):

1- To generate asdf.lisp from source, type `make` in the asdf git checkout.

2- `(load (compile-file ...))` will recompile it every time. You probably want to only compile it once, then overwrite whichever fasl is usually used with it.

3- If you get asdf from quicklisp, as I suppose you do, just replace its obsolete ~/quicklisp/asdf.lisp 2.26 by your asdf.lisp 3.2.1, then blow away the cache in ~/quicklisp/cache/

4- Please complain to Xach about upgrading its asdf to 3.1.7 or 3.2.1. Quicklisp is doing lispers a disservice by distributing 2.26.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, all you need to do is replace 2.6 with 3.2.

### Find out where `asdf.lisp` 2.6 resides.

You can do `(load "asdf")` or `(require "asdf")` and see where it is being loaded from.
Let the path be `my/asdf/directory/asdf.lisp`.

### Replace the file.

```
wget https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/archives/asdf.lisp -O my/asdf/directory/asdf.lisp
```

### Compile the new `asdf`

```
clisp -norc -c my/asdf/directory/asdf.lisp
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, I finally got it, it was a combination of the two answers above.
First, I don't have wget in my system, but I downloaded the file https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/archives/asdf.lisp manually and saved it in the right path.
Then added the two lines

```
(load #P"~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")        ; will load asdf 2.26
(load (compile-file #P"~/rc/asdf.lisp")) ; will load asdf 3 over asdf 2.26.
```

to the file ~/.clisprc.lisp
Now, after restarting CLISP I finally get:

```
(asdf:asdf-version)
"3.2.1"
```

Thanks a lot Sam and Pascal for your help!

Comment: you are loading asdf _twice_, first 2.26, then 3.  this is wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

asdf itself is self-updatable.  You only have to load the latest version.

http://paste.lisp.org/display/350703

So basically, you download an asdf 3 somewhere, say `~/rc/asdf.lisp`
and in your `~/.clisprc.lisp` you put:

```
(load #P"~/quicklisp/setup.lisp")        ; will load asdf 2.26
(load (compile-file #P"~/rc/asdf.lisp")) ; will load asdf 3 over asdf 2.26.
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the latest version of asdf does not contain a file called asdf.lisp.
I have downloaded it with:
git clone https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf.git
and it creates a new folder with some 50 files, but not the one you require.

Comment: @Leo, it's in `"asdf/build/asdf.lisp"`