# how to upgrade ASDF to version 3

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf

I need a version 3 ASDF. I am on GNU CLISP 2.49, Emacs 23.5.1, Ubuntu 16.04, SBCL 1.3.1 Debian.

The current problem is

```
CL-USER> (asdf:asdf-version) => "3.3.2"
```

but

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload :quickproject)
  => Evaluation aborted on
     #<ASDF-2.26:LOAD-SYSTEM-DEFINITION-ERROR #x21C57D9E>
```

My question is; were I to uninstall, purge and then reinstall both Clisp and Emacs, would this provide me with a version 3 ASDF?

I got here by copying a new asdf.lisp and referring to it in ~/.clisprc.lisp

```
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
   (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
     (load quicklisp-init)))
(load (compile-file #P"~/.quicklisp/asdf.lisp"))
```

Perhaps removing reference to this copied asdf.lisp will get me back to version 2 of ASDF.

Re: This earlier Stack Overflow reply [to make from an ASDF Git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45094253/8770050) refers to [ASDF build/install tutorial](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf-install/tutorial/index-save.html#install-asdf) which sure seems complicated.

Comment: Caution, you have a wrong link. Yours' about `asdf-install` and not about installing ASDF…

see https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Upgrading-ASDF upgrading ASDF is as simple as putting it in `~/common-lisp/asdf`. You seem to have 3.3.2 though.

Comment: Are you using CLisp or SBCL?  (You can call `lisp-implementation-type` to find out.)  Those are two different implementations of the language _Common Lisp_.

Comment: Understood, re: this site for programming and development questions. Thank you. The asdf mail-list may be a better place.  

Yes, the [ASDF manual section 3.4](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Replacing-your-implementation_0027s-ASDF) refers to replacing ASDF by using the asdf-tools program. However it is unclear whether the new ASDF Git source must be make/built before running asdf-tools.

I have been using either GNU CLISP 2.49 or SBCL 1.3.1.debian by means of an option at the Slime startup. I assume asdf-tools will need to be run twice,  for each CLISP and SBCL.